# Scala, converting multiple lists to list of tuples

Tags: scala

I have 3 lists like

```
val a = List("a", "b", "c")
val b = List(1, 2, 3)
val c = List(4, 5, 6)
```

I want convert them as follows

```
List(("a", 1, 4), ("b", 2, 5), ("c", 3, 6))
```

Please let me know how to get this result

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Should be easy to achieve:

```
(a zip b) zip c map {
    case ((x, y), z) => (x, y, z)
};
```

Comment: or `(a, b, c).zipped.toList`

Comment: Thank you alex23 and Myserious Dan. It is working. Now it is looking so easy to solve.

Answer (score 14):

If you have two or three lists that you need zipped together you can use **zipped**

```
val a = List("a", "b", "c")
val b = List(1, 2, 3)
val c = List(4, 5, 6) 

(a,b,c).zipped.toList
```

This results in: `List((a,1,4), (b,2,5), (c,3,6))`

Answer (score 6):

Use:

```
(a zip b) zip c map { case ((av,bv),cv) => (av,bv,cv) }
```

Note: This shortens the result list of the shortest of `a,b,c`. If you'd rather have the result list padded with default values, use `zipAll`.